# How do I load the data from the first 2 hive tables into the 3rd one below?

Tags: sql, database, mapreduce, hiveql

**The below is a simplified version of the problem I am facing**

Let's say I have an employee and a department table in Hive. My goal is to load the data from these 2 tables into a 3rd one below. However, the 3rd table has a few dummy columns set to null and will not be filled by data from either of the employee or department tables. Is it possible to still load the employee and department data and just set the other fields to null?

**Employee table(id,first_name,last_name,age,department_id,salary)**

1,John,Smith,23,1,40000

2,Bob,Wilson,25,1,45000

3,Fred,Krug,37,2,75000

4,Jeremy,Fisher,41,3,110000

**Department table(id,name)**

1,Sales

2,IT

3,Marketing

**End result(dummy_column0,employeeID,first_name,last_name,age,salary,department_name,dummy_column1)**

null,1,John,Smith,23,40000,Sales,null

null,2,Bob,Wilson,25,45000,Sales,null

null,3,Fred,Krug,37,75000,IT,null

null,4,Jeremy,Fisher,41,110000,Marketing,null

Question is given the schema of the end result, how do I load the rest of the non-null data into the 3rd table? Any help would be much appreciated! The end results table already exists at this point so I cannot just recreate it from scratch

Comment: `SELECT NULL AS dummy_column0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hive doesn't care of the column names. Its just position of the columns that matter the most. you just have to structure your query in a way so dummy columns have nulls.

```
insert overwrite table tablename
select null, employeeID, first_name,last_name, age, salary, dept.deptName, null
from employee e join dept d on e.dept_id = d.dept_id;
```